# Handling RestAPI login authentication from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a login page in my ReactJS application. Currently for the login authentication I am making an ajax call to rest api endpoint from the component's onclick (on click of login button) action. I don't know much about how to use node.js to handle api calls to rest api. Is there a way that I can specify my root url/hosting address in node.js and just specify the end point in component to make this work. Currently I am doing the authentication like this

```
handleLoginButtonClick() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var that = this;
        let token;
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "https://www.example.application.name.com/auth/login/",
            "method": "POST",
            "credentials": 'include',
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            "data": {
                "password": document.getElementById("password").value,
                "username": document.getElementById("username").value
            },
            success:( response, textStatus, jQxhr )=> {
                this.props.tokenAction(response.auth_token);
            }
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done((response) => {

            token = response.auth_token

            window.localStorage.token_auth = token;
            this.context.router.push('/app')
        });
```

What would be the best way to do this? I have read that node.js can handle this as a session based login. Can someone please explain me?

Comment: What you need is a tutorial on how to set up Node with Express, not an answer.

Comment: @DanielT. can you suggest me some?